# How to read part of the line into array with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `data.txt` to be stored as a data frame:

```
3100  0.000065  0.002070    0.000683    0.000869    0.001768
3211  0.003847  0.002695    0.025881    0.001689    0.012510
1211  0.006311  0.002108    0.000508    0.000301    0.022534
...
```

The first column is `id` and the following are a vector of attributes. How can I read the whole file fast and store the following columns as a vector, so the resulting data frame should be:

```
item_id     attributes
 3100        [0.000065, 0.002070, 0.000683, 0.000869, 0.001768]
 3211        [0.003847, 0.002695, 0.025881, 0.001689, 0.012510]
 ...
```

Do you have any idea about it? Thanks!

EDIT:

The `item_id` indeed contains text characters. So `numpy.loadtext` can not be used directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

This works for ids with strings in them:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', index_col=0, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'attributes': list(df.values)}, index=df.index)
```

Now:

```
>>> df2
                                              attributes
0                                                       
3100a   [6.5e-05, 0.00207, 0.000683, 0.000869, 0.001768]
3211b  [0.003847, 0.002695, 0.025881, 0.001689, 0.01251]
1211c  [0.006311, 0.002108, 0.000508, 0.000301, 0.022...

>>> df2.loc['3100a', 'attributes']
array([  6.50000000e-05,   2.07000000e-03,   6.83000000e-04,
         8.69000000e-04,   1.76800000e-03])
```

### Old Answer

You can use NumPy's `loadtxt` and convert the result into a dataframe:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame({'attributes': list(data[:, 1:])}, index=data[:, 0].astype(int))
```

Now:

```
>>> df
                                             attributes
3100   [6.5e-05, 0.00207, 0.000683, 0.000869, 0.001768]
3211  [0.003847, 0.002695, 0.025881, 0.001689, 0.01251]
1211  [0.006311, 0.002108, 0.000508, 0.000301, 0.022...

>>> df.loc[3100, 'attributes']
array([  6.50000000e-05,   2.07000000e-03,   6.83000000e-04,
         8.69000000e-04,   1.76800000e-03])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your answer seems very promising but unluckily the `id` contains english characters so I got this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: B0006SIBUC`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!